# Webpack share enums in both client and server code

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I have a project with the following structure:

```
|
|--public-|file1.ts
|         |enum.ts
|
|--server/file2.ts
|
```

I am trying to use the enum declared in `enum.ts` in both `file1` and `file2`. But on compilation I get the error `Cannot find module 'public/enum'` in `file2`, `file1` on the other hand is able to succesfully import and use the enum. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to reference it as `../public/enum.ts` from `file2`, `public/enum` would look inside `node_modules/public` for an `enum.js` or `enum.ts` file, followed by `node_modules/public/enum/index.js` or `index.ts` file.

You can also look into TypeScript *and* Webpack aliases (you'll need both for it to work), if you want to refer to it by `public/enum`.